# Remove part of a string with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to strip part of a string (which happens to be a url) with Regex. I'm getting better out regex but can't figure out how to tell it that content before or after the string is optional.  Here is what I have

```
$string='http://www.example.com/username?refid=22';
$new_string= preg_replace('/[/?refid=0-9]+/', '', $string);
echo $new_string;
```

I'm trying to remove the `?refid=22` part to get `http://www.example.com/username`

Ideas?

**EDIT**
I think I need to use Regex instead of explode becuase sometimes the url looks like `http://example.com/profile.php?id=9999&refid=22` In this case I also want to remove the `refid` but not get `id=9999`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) is good for parsing URLs :)

```
$string = 'http://www.example.com/username?refid=22';

$url = parse_url($string);

// Ditch the query.
unset($url['query']);

echo array_shift($url) . '://' . implode($url);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/uVEJvm6l).

#### Output

```
http://www.example.com/username
```

If you only wanted to remove that specific GET param, do this...

```
parse_str($url['query'], $get);

unset($get['refid']);

$url['query'] = http_build_query($get);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/xxol2P3A).

#### Output

```
http://example.com/profile.php?id=9999
```

If you have the extension, you can rebuild the URL with [`http_build_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php).

Otherwise you can make assumptions about username/password/port and build it yourself.

### Update

Just for fun, here is the correction for your regular expression.

```
preg_replace('/\?refid=\d+\z/', '', $string);
```

- `[]` is a character class. You were trying to put a specific order of characters in there.
- `\` is the escape character, not `/`.
- `\d` is a short version of the character class `[0-9]`.
- I put the last character anchor (`\z`) there because it appears it will always be at the end of your string. If not, remove it.

Comment: @BandonRandon My code above covers the case where you only want to remove one GET param.

Comment: @alex, is that method faster/standard over regex?

Comment: @Bandon Regexs are usually slow. Anyway, this method should be easier to read and that's what's important.

Comment: @Alex, sorry to be a pain but it seems that URL is being encoded with `%3B` which is hex for `;` [CodePad](http://codepad.org/sH61P1QM)

Comment: @Bandon What string are you using for input?

Comment: @alex, it's getting a Facebook URL and parsing it then WordPres is encoding it. I'm not sure where the `%3B` is comming from. I tried `urldecode`

Comment: @Alex, I do too :)  Oh well, I just went with `unset($get[';refid']);
unset($get['refid']);` which fixes the problem in a round about way

Answer (score 4):

Dont use regexs if you dont have to

```
echo current( explode( '?', $string ) );
```